# Subscriptions unsubscribe problem in angular

Tags: angular, events, rxjs, subscription

I have an angular app that contains lots of event hooks, a lot of subscriptions etc.

The app is functional at first load, but when I continue using the app, it starts to get slow and practically typing would have about 2 to 3 seconds delay.

What I've done is that I have a `subscriptions: Subscription[]` and then push all the `subscribe`s to it, in `ngOnDestroy`, I just `unsubscribe` from all the subscriptions.

for events I use `fromEvent`.

I have some inputs that hook to `keypress` event and some don't and all the inputs have type delay issue even if no `keypress` hook exists.

```
export class Destroy {
      static subscription(subscription: Subscription): void {
        if (!subscription || subscription.closed) return;
        subscription.unsubscribe();
        subscription = null;
      }
      static subscriptions(subscriptions: Subscription[]): void {
        if (!subscriptions) return;
        subscriptions.forEach(item => {
          if (!item) return;
          Destroy.subscription(item);
        });
      }
  }

@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy{
   subscriptions:Subscription[];
   constructor(){
      this.subscriptions = [];
   }
   ngOnInit(){
      this.subscriptions.push(fromEvent('keydown',/*some inputs*/).subscribe(res=>{/**/}));
   }
   ngOnDestroy(){
      Destroy.subscriptions(this.subscriptions);
   }
}
```

Is this all I can do? I do unsubscribe from all the subscription, but why my app does not work properly after while?

Answer (score 1):

Should work even if you `Destroy` class seems overcomplicated.

anyway, to narrow down your problem you should add 2 `console.log`:

```js
static subscription(subscription: Subscription): void {
    if (!subscription || subscription.closed) return;
    subscription.unsubscribe();
    console.log('unsubscribed');
    subscription = null;
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.subscriptions.push(fromEvent('keydown',/*some inputs*/).subscribe(res=>{console.log('key down event')}));
}
```

once you have added those, you can see if all your subscriptions get unsubscribed or not and also if the subscription remains, you should see  "key down event" logged multiple times.

as for the `Destoy` class I would simply do it like this:

```js
ngOnDestroy(){
    subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
}
```

I never had problems with this approach